# I have problem on configuring a canopen network with EL6751 as master and wago 750-838 as slave using my customized EDS file

Tags: serial-communication, twincat, codesys, canopen, communication-protocol

I am working on a project with a Canopen network consisting of a Beckhoff CX2030 controller and an EL6751 Canopen master device. The network also includes a Wago 750-838 PLC followed by several input/output modules acting as slaves.

To transfer the data of specific variables through Canopen, I have generated an EDS file using the Canopen Architect Mini tool. In my EDS file, I have defined the addresses for TPDO objects (e.g., 1A00, 1A01, ...) and the RPDO object (1800).

I have successfully added the EDS file to both the EL6751 master and the slave box, which was identified after scanning IO in TwinCAT 3.

However, the problem I'm encountering is that the TPDO and RPDO objects are being filled with default addresses of IOs instead of the addresses I defined in my EDS file. For example, the address 1A00 is filled with 6000, while in my EDS file, I used A0C0 for this object.

Interestingly, when I navigate to the COE ONLINE tab and select "show offline data," the content matches my EDS file. But when I uncheck the "show offline data" option, the default TPDO and RPDO addresses are filled instead.

To troubleshoot, I have manually modified the process data on the EL6751 in TwinCAT 3, both in the PDO list and the PDO content. However, even after activating the program, the default data continues to appear in the PDO content box.

I'm seeking guidance on how to resolve this issue. Any insights, suggestions, or potential solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your assistance!